# How to change shutdown delay?

Tags: kde, plasma-5

I want to change the the shutdown delay from 30 seconds to 60 seconds

[This](https://old.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/69qus4/how_to_increase_the_shut_down_time_from_the/) has some discussion but is 5 years old.

Operating System: Ubuntu Studio 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.6
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-47-lowlatency (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
Memory: 7.7 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 4600

Comment: Well, that answer there is correct.  Just because it may seem old at 5 year, the settings are still very much the same today.

Comment: sleep 60; 'sudo shutdown now'
into a script, keyboard shortcut and in sudoers using visudo for no password prompt.

Comment: @pierrely: Thanks for reply. I tried your suggestion and it does work. Use does not use the same route the Plasma is using such that there is no way to cancel the shutdown command.

Comment: sorry, I am not sure what you are saying. was my comment a solution? or do you want to stop a user from interrupting it?

Comment: There are 2 desirable features of this particular dialog box: 1. The countdown (which defaults to 30 and I would like to change to 60). 2. The ability to cancel the shutdown